# how to implement multiple scrollable sticky headers in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile

Please see below [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-bSKlN7IpwgQNoVP1-q0YfSh9piGlxal/view?usp=sharing) on what I am trying to achieve, I have a screens with multiple Flatlists with Data and other items, I want each header to stick as users is scrolling through different sections.
I have tried using stickyheaders props that comes with React Native flatlist but that only works for one flatlist, I am looking for a solution that takes care of multiple sticky headers.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use single flatlist in a screen to acheive this,
there is a ListHeaderComponent and ListFooterComponent in flatlist, you can try adding items in header

ScrollView/Flatlist has a property stickyHeaderIndices,
you can give values for example stickyHeaderIndices={[0,3,5]}

in this example scroll, first item will stop, then 3rd then 5,

Comment: Thanks! this worked, but I had to user scrollview stickyHeaderIndices because it's kind of difficult to convert all my items on the page to Flatlist data

Comment: it is only sticking single item @Nikhil bhatia

Comment: you have to wrap every element in separate <View>, so it identifies first view as 0